# How can I remove everything between two brackets tags using C#

Tags: c#, regex

Input: I found [B]not a[/B] a single way [B]to do[/B] doing this.

Output will be: I found a single way doing this.

My code:

```
string input = "I found [B]not a[/B] a single way [B]to do[/B] doing this.";

string regex = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: @Wiktor the question marked as duplicate is not a duplicate. This question asks to remove the tags and the text between. Those questions just ask to remove the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern: `\[[^\]]+\]`.

Explamnation: it will match `[` first and then everything that isn't `]`, until `]`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mT9llm/1)

Comment: Thank you Michał.

Comment: If it helped you, you should accept the answer (green check mark on the left).

Answer (score 1):

So this is a tested solution and it works:

```
  string output = Regex.Replace("I found [B]not a[/B] a single way [B]to do[/B] doing this.", @"\[.?\].*?\[\/.?\]", "");
```

How? Well the trick is to remove everything between match `[something] [/something]` the text between the tags is expressed as `.?`

Comment: It works. Thank you Matěj.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Regex.Replace("I found [B]not a[/B] a single way [B]to do[/B] doing this.", @"\[(.*?)].*?\[/\1]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Breaking it down

- `\[(.*?)]` - this will match any tag within [ ], for example [B], and also capture the tag (excluding [ ])
- `.*?` will match everything up to the next part of the pattern
- `\[/\1]` will match the corresponding [/TAG]

I took the liberty of adding IgnoreCase so that it will match case insensitively.

Comment: Oh, we answered the same time. But your explanation is even better than mine. Well written

Comment: @MatějŠtágl Thanks :)